# SpriteKit Actions.sks Xcode 8.3.3 "No Preview Scene Selected"

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm new to SpriteKit so I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong here or is it just a minor Xcode bug, but can someone explain to me how am I suppose to select a preview scene? Even if I create multiple dummy scenes and switch between them nothing happens

[image: It doesn't matter which scene (lower right corner) is selected the "No Preview Scene Selected" doesn't disappear]

I've read about this issue in a different thread but is it possible that they still haven't fixed it since Xcode 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug. 
In xcode 9 it is fixed.
At this point you have only two options :

1. wait for Xcode 9
2. download beta version (which is not yet really stable)